# Parse portal URL

Tags: java, string, parsing

How would you parse the bold part of URL into the String?Only ways which comes into my mind are crazy substrings and indexOfs and that just doesn't seem to me as a right way...And I am not particularly strong in regexps so any help is appreciated.

http://url.com/portal/classic/showcase?portal%3AwindowState=normal&navigationalstate=JBPNS_rO0ABXelAARkZW1vAAAAAQAHdG9vbEJhcgAQX2pzZkJyaWRnZVZpZXdJZAAAAAEAIS9yaWNoZmFjZXMvY29tcG9uZW50LXNhbXBsZS54aHRtbAAcamF2YXgucG9ydGxldC5mYWNlcy5WaWV3TGluawAAAAEABHRydWUABHNraW4AAAABAAdibHVlU2t5AAZzYW1wbGUAAAABAAd0b29sQmFyAAdfX0VPRl9f&portal%3AcomponentId=f708c77a-5730-44dd-b1f8-59215adca680&portal%3AresourceID=**/images/icons/create_doc.gif**&portal%3AcacheLevel=PAGE&portal%3Atype=resource&portal%3AportletMode=view"

P.S. It's a portal URL but it doesn't really matter because I only have JDK without portlet tools at my disposal:)

Comment: `I am not particularly strong in regexps` -- Why not give it a try?  And you might be very strong eventually.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I will, I keep postponing it for too long:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept a hack, you don't need to be strong in regexps.

`substring`s and `indexOf`s:

```
String s = "http://url.com/portal/classic/showcase?portal%3AwindowState=normal&navigationalstate=JBPNS_rO0ABXelAARkZW1vAAAAAQAHdG9vbEJhcgAQX2pzZkJyaWRnZVZpZXdJZAAAAAEAIS9yaWNoZmFjZXMvY29tcG9uZW50LXNhbXBsZS54aHRtbAAcamF2YXgucG9ydGxldC5mYWNlcy5WaWV3TGluawAAAAEABHRydWUABHNraW4AAAABAAdibHVlU2t5AAZzYW1wbGUAAAABAAd0b29sQmFyAAdfX0VPRl9f&portal%3AcomponentId=f708c77a-5730-44dd-b1f8-59215adca680&portal%3AresourceID=/images/icons/create_doc.gif&portal%3AcacheLevel=PAGE&portal%3Atype=resource&portal%3AportletMode=view";
String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("resourceID=") + "resourceID=".length());
System.out.println(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf('&')));
```

regexes

```
Pattern pat =  Pattern.compile("resourceID=(.*?)&");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);
mat.find();
System.out.println(mat.group(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Apache URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) can do this for you.

```
public static List<NameValuePair> parse(URI uri,
                        String encoding)
```

I would recommend using such a library in preference to regular expressions for this sort of this. There will be edge cases etc. which the Apache library has encountered previously and will be coded for.